# Count cells that have criteria matching one cell in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns of zip codes. I would like to count how many zip codes in column A are also listed in column B.

Up until now I used a `=COUNTIF` expression, and entered in all the zip codes from column B, but it took forever to put them all in manually, and I'd like to write it in VBA.

My current expression:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A2000,{"45390","45401","45402","45403","45404","45405","45406","45409","45410","45412",etc etc })
```

I'm not really sure where to start though. I could use the VBA countif, but from what I can tell I would have to input all the zip codes manually again, and I'd like to just compare it to all the codes in the range.

```
Sum(COUNTIF(A:A,{""45390"",""45401"", etc etc}))
```

Comment: Why not `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A:A,B1:B20))`

Comment: @ScottCraner you're a lifesaver! Thank you! Is there a way to use formulas in VBA?

Comment: @angoulvm yes `.Formula` property of range. eg `Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C1").Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A:A,B1:B20))" `

Comment: Or if you mean get the result in VBA: `tot = Sheet1.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A:A,B1:B20))")`

Comment: @TimWilliams That's what I was looking for, but when I use that I get a syntax error. I've got `Dim X as Integer     X = Sheet1.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF("G:G","X1:X44"))") `

Comment: You added `"` that are not in @TimWilliams code.

Comment: @ScottCraner my bad! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You've got several good answers in the comments. Here's a User Defined function that I think should perform pretty fast. I might test it against Scott's answer but I think it performs pretty fast.

```
Function CountFaster(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Long
Dim qRng() As Variant

Set rng1 = Intersect(rng1, rng1.Worksheet.UsedRange)
Set rng2 = Intersect(rng2, rng1.Worksheet.UsedRange)

qRng = rng1

Dim e As Variant

'Fast way to loop through a range by setting to variant
For Each e In qRng
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(e, rng2, 0)) Then
        CountFaster = CountFaster + 1
    End If
Next


End Function
```

**Update** that will come as a surprise to no one, my UDF got crushed by Scott Cramer's comment. For every 100k cells, mine took about 6 seconds, his 1. I guess that's what happens when you race a guy with 50 times higher or a rating than you... Anyway, if anyone wants the macro file to do their own timing, [it's here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9gfwJBETmXkqxl8Oyfw)